# Incircle Excircle problem of a triangle

Tags: geometry

The incircle of $\triangle ABC$ touches the sides $AC$ and $BC$ at points $K$ and $L$ respectively. The $B$ excircle touches the side $AC$ of this triangle at point $P$. The segment $AL$ intersects the inscribed circle second time at point $S$. Line $KL$ intersects the circumbrised circle of triangle $ASK$ for the second time at point $M$. Prove that $PL=PM$.

I tried to prove if point $P$ is the circumcentre of $\triangle AML$ but couldn't prove. Though I see that $PK$ is perpendicular to $CM$. Also I know $AK=PC$.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please share a diagram

Comment: I don't have the diagram the question was like this only and my diagram is very bad

Comment: Then use geogebra (http://geogebra.com/geometry) and draw a neat diagram. That is your starting point to see the problem clearly and may be you get further ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe that, $\triangle PAM\cong \triangle LCP$ since $PC=AK=AM$($\angle AMK=\angle AKM$ through angle chasing), $AP=KC=LC$ and $\angle MAP= \angle PCL$. Hence, $PL=PM$.